# If there were a planet with oceans tall enough saturn fitted in, would it be floating around?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, density

In this morning I read an article that claimed

(translated into english, so emphasis mine)

> Saturn is so slight<sup>**1**</sup> it would float around in an ocean.

So appart the missleading wording of its ability to swim by its weight, I started a thought experiment.

Given there would be an planetary body, tall enough to have a little cute saturn floating around in its oceans<sup>2</sup>.

Is that really what would happen? just floating around? No chemical reactions of gas and H2O? No gravity that would crunch things into each other untill there is just some H2O-Saturnish spagethi composition left?

So my question is:

Given an ocean tall enough to be able to fully cover saturn in it, leaving out the question hwo it got there and assuming there was no disastrous violent entry and crash into the ocean surface, so it just appeared there,

**what would actually happen? Would it really be floating around?**

---

<sup>1</sup>note I used the word slight, since the word they used would refer to weight while we have in german language an fitting word for the oppsite of dense they (probably intentionaly or at least due to a lack of knowledge) have chosen not to use that word, so they express the ability to swim comes from weight and not from density. And a uneducated reader might now assume the whole mass of saturn would weight like 100 kilo gramms

<sup>2</sup>even this makes me doubt. Since it feels as this seems to be pretty unlikely if not even possible to have a body of that size where most of the ocean remains liquid water on so deep layers.

Comment: So you have gravity to cause buoyancy, but you don't have gravity to tear a planet apart or to have the planet suck up the ocean...?

Comment: @CuriousOne: I wasn't intentionally refering to buoyancy. I just tryed to summarize the sucking of ocean or the tearing apart of the planet into one sentence. But I jhad actually this exact 2 cases in mind.

Comment: @AnubhavGoel: yeah ofcourse they didn't refer to it. They also probably didn't claim that gravity would be irrelevant here and jsut left it out. But that doesn't make my thought experiment off-topic, does it?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel: Feel free to put this as an answer.

Comment: I don't think a water planet large enough to fit Saturn can even exist, at least yet. The internal heat would keep the ocean in a state of superheated steam.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Thats what I mentioned in the 2nd footnote. But that one is in my opinion one of the not so big problems as I guess at least we could assume that one to exist.

Comment: That's too small for me to read, even with glasses. Be merciful with old men and use a normal size font. Did you calculate the potential energy, by the way? How bad will it heat things up as the core sinks and dissolves? :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne: Nice suggestion. I had multiple times the assumption my footnotes had been ignored. Maybe I was right adn it was because of that. Uhm... No I didn't I have admit I don't even know how to.

Comment: Ah! Now I can read them. Much obliged!

Comment: So basically, your question is "Is Saturn's (mean?) density such that it could float in water?"

Comment: @KyleKanos: No my main question is as it stands "Would Saturn be able to float around without gravity (or what ever else) doing its job and put the planet into somethign that doesn't is really saturn anymore.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Thanks, you enlightened me. This is the bas feedback I ever got. declaring a thought experiment as none sense. I'm just curious, is it my expectation that there are forces like gravity? Or that elements react with each other? Or what else is the none sense you're talking about?

Comment: How about the lack of correct grammar or sentence structure? And then what is there doesn't make physical sense (how can something float (on a surface?) without gravity? Are you expecting Saturn to melt or something when it is in water?)

Comment: @KyleKanos: I don't have it neccessary to take such haughtiness and explain something I allready wrote and getting insulted meanwhile. Nice to see you getting to your point that your own claim makes no sense. No clue while you brought even up "non gravity" then. What I expect to happen I summarized in the OP so just scroll up... But I'm curious about what you expect to hapen?! you expect saturn to remain in its current form?!

Comment: I expect questions to be about real, actual physics and not hypothetical (or otherwise fictional) events. Your question, therefore is off topic. You might be interested in [worldbuilding.se], however.

Comment: @KyleKanos: Ok while this is actually a thought experiment triggered by a actual case (where a newspaper at least claimed this could happen and I couldn't imagine so.) I still aggree that this might better fit to worldbuilding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [How much water is needed for Saturn to float in?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/176742/how-much-water-is-needed-for-saturn-to-float-in)

Answer (score 1):

What happens when you put a sponge in bucket water? It initially floats and then sink. But what ,if you wrap sponge with polythene? It continue to float. Similarly, text in article meant no interaction with water.

If you put Saturn uncovered in ocean, outer gases would fly off, liquid would dissolve, leaving behind hard core to sink.

Bigger is the size of planet, greater the atmosphere it has(compare moon and earth).
So, even such large planet will have all sorts of layers, solid, liquid and gas.

At appropriate layer, Saturn can then float if it remains intact.

So, core would sink to crust bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Its just a figure of speech to  emphasising the difference in density between the materials of the planet and the density of the water.

Nothing will float forever. Even polyethylene, which is obviously lighter than water will go into breakdown in billion years.

Answer (score 0):

This article you refer to is probably commenting on the average density of planet saturn which is in fact less than the density of water, hence if we could put saturn in a pool or ocean it would float.

Comment: And there wouldn't be any devastating interactions that would deform/destroy Saturn in long, if not even short term?

Comment: Yeah, I'm talking about: Ould their really be a state of floating or would it just be a single violent reacting mess? And if so, what would the stages and the outcome be like.

Comment: Saturn's atmosphere is composed of mainly hydrogen and helium with small trace volumes of methane and ammonia. I don't know much of chemistry but water doesn't form any violent compound on reacting with these hence these layers of Saturn will simply not react with water resulting in separation of gases and solid-land and core of Saturn. The next phase will probably be the sinking of solid material of Saturn (core) into water as due to separation the density of left Saturn (without atmosphere) will be more than that of water.

Comment: And the gravity of such a great planet that has such tall oceans wouldn't act too violent on saturn?

Comment: This type of planet would simply not exist as from what i know it would be massive enough to start burning hydrogen as fuel and would turn into a brown dwarf star. So this is really just a very hypothetical situation i.e. such a massive planet, great depth oceans etc.

Comment: please just edit it into your answer. Thats not quiet the answer I was looking for, but if you can reason why this can't happen with that reason. It is satissfying me.